# Extracting and splitting a MP3 audio stream from an AVI file

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, avi

I want to develop a desktop application by programming in `C#` and using the `.Net framework 4`.
The goal of my application is to extract a `MP3` audio stream from a supplied `AVI` file.
I have learned from the Internet that an `AVI` file is a container and it might contain different audio streams.
If the supplied `AVI` file contains one MP3 audio stream at least then I want to extract it and split it.
I want to split the `MP3` audio stream into `MP3` audio parts identified with a start time and an end time.

I have looked on the Internet for any .Net library I could use but without success.
Does someone know what documented .Net library would be useful ?

Comment: If you want to create such a program, why not *actually* program the essential part (i.e. the splitter) and learn something along the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:
[**Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library)

It is targeted at AVI video but there might be some clues as how to use the same methods to extract the audio only.
Either use it as-is or use the example to incorporate what you need into your own code.

Comment: I can use the AviManager.GetWaveStream method to retrieve an audio stream from an AVI file. But I have not found a method to create a MP3 file from an audio stream. The only files I can create are AVI files.

Comment: Hey i'm trying to use the avi dll functions friom the link but it doesn't seem to work on .net 4.0 but does on .net 4.5 any ideas how i could get it to work?  I have no choice and have to use 4.0 due to needing to support xp

Answer (score 0):

Since tools for this task already exist, I see no point in creating another one unless you're curious about *how* to do this yourself and learn something new.

If so, using a ready-made library would defeat the entire idea of learning something which is why I strongly recommend you try implementing the splitter yourself.

You can find [**descriptions of the AVI file format online**](http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf), that should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation. I will read it and then I will use the Windows AVIFile library to operate on MP3 audio streams from an AVI file. If I spend too much time then I will look at the wrapper library mentionned by johannie.